# SQL Query Date Not Before

Tags: sql

I'm wondering if there's a SQL clause for "date is not before"?

I don't want date greater than, because some of my values are blank, and I want the clause to capture those blank values.

So basically, date not before 17/03/2021 would bring back a count of "27".

| date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 16/03/2021 | 5 |
| 17/03/2021 | 4 |
| 18/03/2021 | 12 |
| blank | 11 |

Many thanks,

Nam

Comment: Column data type? Which dbms?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a where clause something like the following...

```
WHERE (Date >= '20210317' OR Date IS NULL)
```

Comment: A column named `20210317`?

Comment: No sorry. that should be in single quotes as the value to get dates greater than. It's just in ISO format

Comment: Pretty sure the problem here is that they just need to get nulls as well as dates greater than x.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that "blank" means `NULL`.  In Standard SQL, you need an explicit comparison for this.  And you need a date constant:

```
where "date" >= date '2021-03-17' or "date" is null
```

You can also use `coalesce()`:

```
where coalesce("date", '2199-12-31') >= date '2021-03-17'
```

but this can prevent the optimizer from choosing the best execution plan.

Comment: Or you could have just ticked my answer as it is basically the same as yours but without the unneccesary coalesce bit.

Comment: @AndyRobertson . . . There is a big different between a string `'20210317'` and a date literal -- that is, in any database except SQL Server.  The question doesn't specify the database.

Comment: The answer is "or is null" in essence the rest is fluff. I gave that answer but I never expect any credit on this platform just criticism from pedants.